# Javascript delete object.property not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to delete an object's property but the property does not get deleted at all...

What I have:

```
var tagFound = yield tags.findById(this.params.tagId);
debug('prior delete: %j', tagFound);
delete tagFound.password;
debug('after delete: %j', tagFound);
```

What I get:

```
api_v1 prior delete: {"_id":"55e064e9727b44c32a262c0f","expires":"2015-08-29T13:40:57.673Z","password":"$2a$08$hucJyHIU5gholAB1L.wVKeFoTmvFho9xFiJAAvmwmtKphLuJ9Hq4K","type":"free","name":"teste","__v":0,"visible":true,"locations":[{"latitude":65.9667,"longitude":-18.5333,"_id":"55e064e9727b44c32a262c10","timestamp":"2015-08-28T13:40:57.572Z"}]}

api_v1 after delete: {"_id":"55e064e9727b44c32a262c0f","expires":"2015-08-29T13:40:57.673Z","password":"$2a$08$hucJyHIU5gholAB1L.wVKeFoTmvFho9xFiJAAvmwmtKphLuJ9Hq4K","type":"free","name":"teste","__v":0,"visible":true,"locations":[{"latitude":65.9667,"longitude":-18.5333,"_id":"55e064e9727b44c32a262c10","timestamp":"2015-08-28T13:40:57.572Z"}]}
```

Maybe my eyes are too tired, but I simply cannot figure this out, does anybody see something obvious that I am missing here?

Update: I put this into http://jsfiddle.net/fc8mohwp/, the problem is, it is working there, but not here (iojs). Should there be any difference?

Comment: what does `delete` return?

Comment: Where does `tagFound` come from? If the password field comes from a HTML-Tag than it cannot be deleted. Only user defined properties can be deleted. At least that's the case in a browser but probably something similar is happening in node.

Comment: Delete returns true. tagFound comes from a mongoDB document

Comment: The object property may not be writable.

Comment: please remove `node.js` tag and insert `io.js`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certain variables cannot be deleted depending on the context of how they are declared.  For example, you can't delete variables that have been defined in a global scope.

I hate to post a link answer, but this blog post describes all the rules and edge cases with using delete.  It is quite a bit for me to include in a SO post

[Using delete in Javascript](http://blog.caplin.com/2012/01/31/javascript-is-hard-part-3-you-cant-delete-with-delete/)

Comment: tagFound is declared locally, but it comes from an yield statement, could that be the problem?

Comment: @rbaprado Possible.  Where is tags.findById coming from?  Is this a DOM element that your trying to delete?

Comment: tags.findById is a wrapper for mongoose's findOne, no DOM here

Comment: @rbaprado Gotcha.  Hard to say then.  The mongoose library might be doing something goofy to try and protect it's objects.  You could try doing a deep copy of the object by converting it to and from a JSON string.  That might allow you to declare a local copy of the variable which would allow you to delete it.

Comment: As ugly as it gets, tagFound = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mobtagFound)) did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can have multiple reasons for example the password field can't be changed or the password field is coming from the prototype chain.

You can debug this with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(tagFound, 'password');`

Comment: Then it is coming from the prototype.

Answer (score -3):

You can delete a property from a javascript object by using the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator

delete myObject.proportyname;

Comment: delete is an operator, not a function. Therefore this should be `delete myObject.propertyname`